# How Magento router initialize gespecific Action Controller and Action method

Tags: magento

I am able to understand how routers are collected using collectRoutes() function. Then how magento tries to match router for the requested URL using match() function in dispatch() method.
But how magneto router initialize the specific Action Controller and Action method ?
What is the utility of controller_front_send_response_before and controller_front_send_response_after events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this is very easy (if I understand your question correctly).

URL always has a `route/controller/action` structure.

So once Magento resolved the `route` (you said that you got how it works) it just uses `controller` token as the first part of a classname of your controller. So for instance if your controller token is `mymodule` and your extension prefix is `Mygroup_Myextension` it will try to instantiate `Mygroup_Myextension_MymoduleController`. That means your file have to be located in `app/code/[community-or-local]/Mygroup/Myextension/controllers/MymoduleController.php`.

Then Magento will use an `action` token to call a method inside of your class. So in case of `action` token set as `myaction` Magento will try to call `myactionAction()` method.

In fact both `controller` and `action` tokens can be omitted. In this case Magento will try to instantiate `Mygroup_Myextension_IndexController` and call `indexAction()` method of your extension.